# Hyper-VM Won’t Connect to Internet

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, internet-connection, windows-server-2019

I am using Hyper-V on my windows 10 pro laptop, inside of it I am creating a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Evaluation VM. Later on, inside of this I will need to put AD DS on this as well as Hyper-V (inside the server) for making more VMs, as per class requirements. During installation of the vm, I have tried both default switch and the option where you can simply create a vswitch later.

When I have my server booted up, it is not connected to the internet. (I need it to be able to connect for this class). When I go to create an external vswitch through virtual switch manager, select my adapter (my adapter connects via wifi as it is a wireless network adapter), and check the box next to “Allow management operating system to share this network adapter”, press apply, I get disconnected from the internet on my host and then on hyper-v I get this message:

**Error applying Virtual Switch Properties changes**
Adding ports to the switch “vNIC” failed.
The operation failed because the object was not found.

If I try it again, it gives a different error message:

**Error applying Virtual Switch Properties changes**
Failed while adding virtual Ethernet switch connections.
Ethernet port
‘{…}’ bind failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0x800700B7)

I see it’s trying to add virtual ethernet switch connections, but my adapter is wireless.

How do I go about getting my VM connected to the internet?

Note:
I originally tried making this vm in VirtualBox and it worked fine until as part of the class requirement, I needed to also install hyper-v to get a vm of windows 10 on it. SLAT is not possible for Hyper-V in VirtualBox.

Comment: I have also given it a static IP address and default gateway, however it says “unidentified network”.

Comment: I see it’s trying to add virtual ethernet switch connections, but my adapter is wireless.    ... That should not matter. The default switch and indeed a New External Switch both work fine on my wireless X1 laptop here. Given the error, consider reinstalling Hyper-V. Make sure machines have been backed up, remove Hyper-V (Windows Features), restart, add back Hyper-V, restart and test.

Comment: @John, that worked, thank you so much! You’re a life saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see it’s trying to add virtual ethernet switch connections, but my
> adapter is wireless.

That should not matter. The default switch and indeed a New External Switch both work fine on my wireless X1 laptop here.

Given the error, consider reinstalling Hyper-V. Make sure machines have been backed up, remove Hyper-V (Windows Features), restart, add back Hyper-V, restart and test.

This may well fix the problem.